# Remove disable page with fixed hedaer in jquery mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile

I developed a project in jquery mobile which have fixed header. its working fine in laptop browser but when I run in mobile browser then after browse some pages my mobile getting stuck because jquery mobile keep cache of previous page. so to remove previous pages I added below code
`$(document).on( "pageshow", function( event, data ){
        $('div[data-role=page]:hidden').remove();
});`

It also worked fine but now when i clicked on a link first time it remove previous page data as well padding-top from ui-page which was added for fixed header. now if I goes to next page and again comes on this page its work fine.
Please suggest, Thanks!!!

Comment: check here on how Dom Cache  works the (Default: false) does not keep pages in Dom after you navigated from them anyway so what you are doing  is pointless -- https://api.jquerymobile.com/page/#option-domCache

Comment: what is '.selector' ?? is it class of page?? what if i need to apply it for all pages or where i need to add this code??
`$( ".selector" ).page({
  domCache: true
});`

Comment: $( ".selector" ) is the pages id  i.e $( "#page1" )  -- .page({ domCache: true }); -- basically says put this page in the DOM (document object model) i.e in memory so you can access and manipulate stuff within the page at any time if need too

Comment: But I have too many pages and each page have different page id so its not possible to add this code in each pages....is there any code which i can put in single page or in head section so it will apply for all pages?

Comment: Not sure, probably -- you can alos add this to each page  (data-dom-cache="true") and it will act the same